# Android google maps refresh map

Tags: android, google-maps

how can I refresh the map type of a google map during runtime? I want the user to have an option to select a map type in the app settings and want it to get updated. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/12/set-map-type-of-googlemap.html

```
   FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
    = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

   myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

   //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
   //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
   //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
   myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
```